# How get content from specific link?

Tags: php

I have link in specific variable eg.

```
$link = 'http://google.com'
```

and I try to get content from this link with function fopen.
Eg. : $var = fopen("'".$link."'", "rb");

```
echo stream_get_contents($var); ,
```

but without success. Error is

> Warning: file_get_contents('http://google.com'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/...

If I use directly

```
$var = fopen('http://google.com', "rb");
echo stream_get_contents($var)
```

this work perfectly?
How do I fix this or what method to use if I link is a variable?

Comment: Use proper formatting.

Comment: works for any website

Comment: Then use `$link = "http://www.google.com";` with `$var = fopen($link, "rb");`  that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted code, this worked for me. Try it using this method:

```
<?php
$link = "http://www.google.com";
$var = fopen($link, "rb");
echo stream_get_contents($var)
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This always worked for me.

```
$url  = 'http://google.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```